# SeriLog with AppInsights not writing to AppInsights

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-application-insights, serilog

I am writing logs using Serilog with appinsights on an .NET CORE 2.0 project.

i have configured SeriLog as follows,

```
var loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithDemystifiedStackTraces();
```

and writing to appInsights as follows,

```
 loggerConfiguration = loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.ApplicationInsightsTraces(appInsightsIntrumentationKey, serilogLevel)
.WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(contentRoot, "Logs/log-{Date}.log"), retainedFileCountLimit: 14);
```

i see the log generated inside the logs folder, but i dont see anything in appInsights.

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked out [official README](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights/blob/master/README.md)? They have some tips regarding flushing/persistence of logged events. Also, are you sure these traces don't end up in 'Custom events' section?

Comment: yes i read that, i dont see even a single log in app insights

Comment: Same prob. Is it going to be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to do it [as documented](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights/blob/master/README.md#configuring-with-readfromconfiguration)

```
    "ApplicationInsights": {
        "InstrumentationKey": "7334f234-42c9-4a1f-b35d-4969d48020d4",
        "EnableAdaptiveSampling": false,
        "EnablePerformanceCounterCollectionModule": false
    },
    "Serilog": {
        "WriteTo": [
            { "Name": "Console" },
            {
                "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
                "Args": {
                    "instrumentationKey": "7334f234-42c9-4a1f-b35d-4969d48020d4",
                    "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

it works from both Azure App Service and dev computer

Program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog() // added to embed serilog
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration).CreateLogger();
}
```

sample controller:

```
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BadValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<BadValuesController> _logger;
        public BadValuesController(ILogger<BadValuesController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _logger.LogDebug("ctor");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetData()
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("going to raise 6 from local app");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

There is no need to rebuild application since no `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();` is executed. You may just copy `dll` files to your application and adjust config to turn the AppInsights logging on.

However you do not [have `TelemetryClient` instance](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights/blob/master/README.md#or-where-did-my-messages-go) if there is no source code modifications. So you have to wait a while before can select app insights log.

I've installed NuGet packages

- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore
- Serilog.AspNetCore
- Serilog.Enrichers.Environment
- Serilog.Enrichers.Process
- Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsight

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to install the SDK prior to the Serilog ApplicationInsights sink. If you don't have the SDK, it seems to work but you will end up without any messages in ApplicationInsights.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I will try this but I'd like to know how you figured this out