# ASP.NET Core + ApplicationInsights Logging Errors as Trace

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I am using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore).

I've enabled application insights by adding .UseApplicationInsights() in Programs.cs and in my startup class:

```
    loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices);
```

This all works fine, I am able to see requests in app insights but when I try to log an error (for example in my controller):

```
        _logger.LogError("My Error Log");
        _logger.LogError("Test", new Exception("Test"));
```

Both are logged as trace events and not exceptions in app insights.

How do I make it so it logs as an exception?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to log the error as Exception in app insights, this line of code `_logger.LogError("Test", new Exception("Test"));` should be changed.

Change it to `_logger.LogError(new Exception(), "test");`, which means the `new Exception()` should be the first paramter.

And you can add application insights SDK by right click your project -> add -> Application Insights Telemetry, which is very useful doing some thing automatically(ie.  adding `.UseApplicationInsights() in Programs.cs`):
[image]

I also post my test steps:

1.Adding application insights SDK as mentioned above

2.Add `loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices,LogLevel.Information);` in Startup.cs -> Configure() method, code as below:

```
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                    app.UseHsts();
                }

                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseCookiePolicy();

                app.UseMvc();

                //Add this line of code
                loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices,LogLevel.Information);
            }
```

3.Then in somewhere you wanna log error:

```
        public class AboutModel : PageModel
        {
            private ILogger _logger;

            public AboutModel(ILogger<AboutModel> logger)
            {
                _logger = logger;
            }

            public string Message { get; set; }

            public void OnGet()
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("it is just a test herexxxx");

               //Only this format can log as exception
                _logger.LogError(new Exception(), "it is a new Exceptionxxxx");

               //it will log as trace
                _logger.LogError("error logs xxx");
                Message = "Your application description page.";
            }
        }
```

4.Test result as below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful!

Comment: `loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices,LogLevel.Information);` is now obsolete at least on .Net 5.

Answer (score 8):

Since `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet v2.7` the question and the accepted answer are outdated, as calling `AddApplicationInsights` on `ILoggerFactory` is now obsolete.

Please refer to [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger).

The gist from the docs:

1. `ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider` is enabled by default.
2. Captured log types can be configured in `appsettings.json` (or programmatically if you really need it)

```
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
        },
        "ApplicationInsights": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Error"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP said:

> Both are logged as trace events and not exceptions in app insights.

I was battling that specific issue in a configuration with Serilog and ASP.NET Core 3.1, following the latest recommendations including those of Alex Klaus above.

The solution for me was in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64893138. Specifically I did not have the instrumentation key in the Serilog section. With the instrumentation key in both Application Insights and Serilog sections, exceptions started showing up as exceptions in Azure Application Insights.